# Display data from related table & concatenate with column Yii2 SortableInput

Tags: widget, yii2

I'm using the Kartik's SortableInput widget in a basic Yii2 app, I've been able to generate a list from a table in my db, but the items displayed only show the id of the rows in the tableA. What I want to do is to show a specific column from tableA and another column from tableB that is related to tableA (the relation and join exists in the modelSearch).
This is what I have in my form:

```
<?php
    $items = [];
    $dosis = Dosis::find()
        ->all();
    foreach ($dosis as $key) {
        $items[$key->id_dosis] = [
            'content' => $key->id_dosis,
            'options' => ['data' => ['id_dosis'=>$key->id_dosis]],
        ];
    }
?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'dosis')->widget(SortableInput::classname(), [    
    'items' => $items,
    'hideInput' => false,
    'options' => ['class'=>'form-control', 'readonly'=>true]
    ]);
?>
```

Comment: Use `$key->relationName->fieldName` may work.

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you!, about the second part of the question: can I concatenate a field from tableA with the field obtained on your solution, on the same sortable element? Regards.

Comment: Sure, but you have to concatenate two values using anonymous function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$key->relationName->fieldName`:

```
foreach ($dosis as $key) {
    $items[$key->id_dosis] = [
        'content' => $key->relationName->fieldName,
        'options' => ['data' => ['id_dosis'=>$key->relationName->fieldName]],
    ];
}
```